# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.experimental' has no attribute 'register_filesystem_plugin'

Tags: tensorflow

can't import tensorflow-io, error message as follow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_parquet.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow_io as tfio
  File "/Users/dpwang/opt/anaconda3/envs/inconformity_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_io/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow_io.python.api import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/Users/dpwang/opt/anaconda3/envs/inconformity_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_io/python/api/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow_io.python.ops.io_dataset import IODataset
  File "/Users/dpwang/opt/anaconda3/envs/inconformity_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
    plugin_ops = _load_library("libtensorflow_io_plugins.so", "fs")
  File "/Users/dpwang/opt/anaconda3/envs/inconformity_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py", line 64, in _load_library
    l = load_fn(f)
  File "/Users/dpwang/opt/anaconda3/envs/inconformity_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    load_fn = lambda f: tf.experimental.register_filesystem_plugin(f) is None
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.experimental' has no attribute 'register_filesystem_plugin'
```

my tensorflow is 2.7.0 and and tensorflow-io version is 0.22.0

```
tensorflow                2.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-base           2.0.0           mkl_py37h66b1bf0_0    https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main
tensorflow-estimator      2.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io             0.22.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.22.0                   pypi_0    pypi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

degrade tensorflow-io from 0.22.0 to 0.16.0

pip install -U tensorflow-io==0.16.0

Answer (score -2):

I solved by

pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.7.0 --user